# how to fit wide table on an a4 size paper?

Tags: php, html, css, printing

I want to print a table of report on an a4 size paper , but only a part of the table is getting printed , few columns are being left out.

Can anybody please tell me what might be the problem?

I tried to shrink to fit but , it becomes too small to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the landscape paper mode rather than portrait mode. Next shrink your contents to fit the page. If they don't you can't get entire thing on a single sheet unless you want unreadable font size (read smaller than your eye can read).

Answer (score 1):

It used to be that monitors had a display area smaller than a piece of paper, but now the opposite is true.

You should have stylesheets for both screen and print.  On the print CSS, set the table in percentages, and not ever span more than 100% of the page's width.  For print, especially for reports, the simpler the better.  A clean header is about all you need for aesthetics.

to do that, you just declare 2 stylesheets:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
</style>
```

as well as...

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
</style>
```

There are other media types too:

```
all  
aural    
braille  
embossed
handheld
print   
projection
screen   
tty  
tv
```

Answer (score 0):

If it won't fit using landscape mode, and you're not happy with shrinking it, it just won't fit. Some suggestions:

- Reduce data, if possible
- Play with paper setup in print
  settings
- Play with padding/margin settings if
  applicable

Otherwise, not much you can do. Paper is provided "as is" :P